# Not able to browse api/values/5 using .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have just created a .NET Core WebApi solution although when I hit F5 to launch it the browser displays "site cannot be reached" and debugging stops.  I've included a screen shot below.

I've installed .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle onto the server and HttpPlatformHandler v1.2

I've browsed to the source folder and ran the following command in cmd.exe to publish the site.

```
donet publish
```

The command prompt displayed (see second screen shot)

```
published 1/1 projects successfully.
```

Browsing the published folder I cannot see an *.exe anywhere.

Can anyone suggest how I can hit the api/values/5 route in the browser successfully?

[image]

Many thanks, any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go in the "publish" folder, find your DLL (there isn't .exe for a web project) and launch the app with the "dotnet" command.

An example with my project named "Test"

```
C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test>dotnet publish
Publishing Test for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Project Test (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Configuring the following project for use with IIS: 'C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish'
Updating web.config at 'C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish\web.config'
Configuring project completed successfully
publish: Published to C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish
Published 1/1 projects successfully

C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test>cd ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish

C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish>dotnet test.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\dco\Documents\Workspace\Sandbox\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

And after that you can hit your URL :-)

Comment: @Jamie In addition to Arcord's answer, refer this for publish directory and files understanding - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/directory-structure.html